# How to make "Go to Source" work for file with eps Figures in TexStudio

Tags: texstudio

I am using TexStudio and my TeX file contains a `.eps` figure, which cannot use the `PDF Chain`.  I change it to `DVI->PDF Chain`, and then the PDF file cannot successfully compile. However, I cannot use the fancy 'Go to Source' anymore by right click. How can I make it work again?

Comment: Convert the eps to pdf so that you can continue to use the pdf chain. (In a modern system you can use the package epstopdf to convert the eps on-the-fly).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: Can this feature be embedded into TexStudio?

Comment: Well if your system can use epstopdf (TL 2013 e.g. can) there is no need to embed anything. A simple `\usepackage{epstopdf}` should work.

Answer (score 1):

"Go to Source" is a feature that relies on synctex, which is only available for pdflatex, xelatex and lualatex but not for latex. If you want to use "Go to Source", you'll have to convert your eps files and change to one of the above compilers.